# Angular ng-messages dynamic name with function to do something in the name before rendering

Tags: angularjs, ng-messages

so here is my issue.
im trying to display the ng-messages with this setting

```
    <div ng-messages="flow_form.this[removeSpaces($ctrl.fieldModel.name)].$error" role="alert" ng-if="submitted || flow_form.this[removeSpaces($ctrl.fieldModel.name)].$dirty">
```

so first issue there is the

```
    ng-messages="flow_form.this[removeSpaces($ctrl.fieldModel.name)].$error"
```

the removeSpaces is defined as a function

```
    $scope.removeSpaces = function(nameAttr) {
if (nameAttr) {
  return nameAttr.replace(/\s+/g, '-');
}
```

};

Meanwhile in the ng-if i have this

```
    ng-if="submitted || flow_form.this[removeSpaces($ctrl.fieldModel.name)].$dirty"
```

i dont know if the way i wrote it in the UI is correct.

did anybody had this issue before? can you please help me. I would appreciate any help i can get.

Comment: what is $ctrl?, and what is `fieldModel.name` .Please post some more relevant code

Comment: Hi, @RaviShankar, $ctrl is an object that has fieldModel and that fieldModel contains name which would define the name attribute of inputboxes

Comment: where is it defined , can you show me?

Comment: @RaviShankar its now working only if i remove the removeSpaces function.. 

so it would look like this

ng-messages="flow_form[$ctrl.fieldModel.name].$error"

do you know how to call the function inside the ng-messages?